# I'm trying to make my images fit the container but they are zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my images resize to the size of the container and when resized to tablet or phone view take the size of the container and adjust to resize, however my images are just too zoomed in like this: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

```html
<div class="ps-section--homeCenter" style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr); grid-auto-rows: 213px 213px; grid-gap: 10px; padding:0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;">




  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/400" style=" object-fit: cover; object-position: 50% 50%;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="display:flex;  height: 100%;  align-items:center">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" style="
       max-height:100%; max-width: 100%; align-self:center; " />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;   overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/300" style="object-fit:cover; width: 100%; " />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/800" style="width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" style="width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/600" style="width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" style="width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="imgInGallery" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" style="width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="gallery_container">
    <div class="gallery_Item" style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/800" style="width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/06akm1se/

Comment: Please use CSS. That'll solve half of your problems going forward.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the CSS is inline.

Comment: The fact that the images are zoomed in is because you used ```object-fit: cover```. It means that the image is resized so that there is no whitespace left...

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of photos of differing aspect ratios. Fitting them to a grid, where the row height is the same across all photos in the row you are almost bound to find that some photos can only be accommodated by using cover (as you have done) which means either the sides or the top/bottom will get cropped and the photos appear zoomed in.

Given the selection of aspect ratios I wonder whether a grid (as interpreted by a CSS grid) is the way to go? If you stick with grid then you would probably want to look at using contain rather than cover to ensure all of all photos can be seen - and put up with having differing spaces between them.

However, given the wide selection of aspect ratios, it may be useful to look into a more masonry type of layout, where photos next to each other may have different heights but the whole thing keeps a compact look.

See for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout) for preliminary discussion of a potential CSS feature:

> Masonry layout is a layout method where one axis uses a typical strict grid layout, of most often columns, and the other a masonry layout. On the masonry axis, rather than sticking to a strict grid with gaps being left after shorter items, the items in the following row rise up to completely fill the gaps.

As this is experimental, and only in Firefox at the moment, using a library which will fit your images into columns with each image having its own suitable height may be the way to go. There are several libraries out there that do this though for just two columns it's not too difficult to do the arithmetic for this - to decide where to start the second column.

Answer (score 0):

When using `object-fit: cover` on an image tag, it will essentially act like a background image. It will stretch to fill the container either horizontally or vertically depending on the aspect ratio of the parent and the image itself.

If you don't want the images to stretch or "zoom in", you can use `object-fit: contain`, but then the image won't stretch to fill your container.